# TOP and OUTER APPLY

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

If I have a query like this, will the OUTER APPLY only be applied on the TOP 5 rows of tblA? Or will it be applied on all rows returned from tblA, and only then will the TOP 5 be applicable? I have a lot of rows in tblA, and I dont want the OUTER APPLY to run on all the rows.

```
SELECT TOP 5 ACol1, ACol2, b.BCol2
FROM tblA
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 BCol2 
             FROM tblB WHERE BCol1 = tblA.ACol1
             ORDER BY ins_dtim DESC) b
ORDER BY tblA.ACol3
```

Comment: `outer apply` returns a catersian product but will also return 0 if no match is found from the anchor, in short it will return each top 1 from the top 5 result.... to simplify `outer apply` is similar to a `subquery field` in the `select statement` but the difference is a subquery can only return 1 field.

Comment: Perhaps looking at the query plan would tell you?

Comment: If you are doing `TOP 1` to restrict the right table expression of the `OUTER APPLY` why not just do a `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: @NetMage Because more than on record from tblB might match with tblA. Though in this case an additional GROUP BY might be better

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn But how is that relevant when the subquery has `TOP 1` in it? Won't that force a single return regardless of the number of matches?

Comment: @NetMage Yes. But the `LEFT JOIN` you suggested would not, mean it isn't a good replacement for the APPLY by itself.

Comment: I understand (lightbulb)! Wouldn't applying a `TOP 5` directly to `tblA` first in the `FROM` ensure that only 5 rows from `tblA` are processing by the `OUTER APPLY`?

Comment: Sorry, the query in OUTER APPLY actually has on ORDER BY clause. I need to get the latest value from tblB for the first 5 rows in tblA. So I cannot replace it by a LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the OUTER APPLY will be done on all the rows first, and then the TOP 5 will be returned.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, any use of `TOP` without a matching `ORDER BY` is very likely a mistake. This applies to **both parts** of your existing query: the `TOP 1` *and* `TOP 5` statements.

That out of the way, for this query, you may be better off like this:

```
SELECT TOP 5 ACol1, ACol2, MAX(b.BCol2) AS BCol2
FROM tblA a
LEFT JOIN tblB b ON b.BCol1 = a.ACol1
GROUP BY a.ACol1, a.ACol2
```

It should work as well as what you have as long as `ACol1` and `ACol2` are reasonably unique. What you have now might allow for duplicate `ACol1, ACol2` pairs if that data exists in your table. This will not. But since you don't care about ORDER, you have no grounds to complain if this returns different values, as long as they match real data in the table.

---

But I understand all this is also likely a simplified version of the problem, so I will address the question directly in two ways.

First, the right thing to do when you're unclear on behavior is to check the execution plan. You don't need to be an execution plan expert to determine what is going on. If you're not familiar with the meaning for each of the nodes, Google can help you understand it.

From the other direction, don't quote me on this, but I would expect Sql Server to only use it 5 times in this specific case. I think that's what you were hoping to hear. **But don't count on that in the general case.**

If you have an `ORDER BY` clause for the query, as you should do whenever you use `TOP`, then Sql Server can't know which results to return until it checks all the possibilities. Furthermore, if that `ORDER BY` is determined by any fields from the APPLY results, Sql Server will **definitely** have to run the sub query for every possible record. Otherwise, it would have no way to know which records it needs.

Finally, in many cases the query optimizer will handle an `APPLY` as something more closely resembling a `JOIN` than a sub query. Even when it seems like it needs to compute the results for every record, it still might be faster than you expect.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited it. This was a simplified version of the problem. I do have ORDER BY for both queries. I did check the execution plan, but I can't really tell where the TOP is applied. I would post a screenshot here if I could, but I dont know how.